execute sql file option in navicat is greyed out
I'm new to mysql and navicat so I don't know what I'm doing.  I have an sql file which I'm trying to execute and convert into a database but I'm a little clueless as to the first steps.  All the tutorials I see on youtube suggest simply selecting the execute sql file option but on my computer that option is greyed out, as seen here:


I needed to click on Wiktionary, not mysql
